# Find minimal set of operations that modify array to meet condition

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of sorted numbers:

```
arr = [-0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.2]
```

I want the difference (dist below) between consecutive numbers for that array to be above a given threshold. For example, if threshold is 0.25:

```
dist = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4] # must be >0.25 for all elements
```

`arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are too close to each other, so one of them must be modified. In this case the desired array would be:

```
good_array = [-0.25, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.2] # all elements distance > threshold
```

In order to obtain good_array, I want to modify the minimum amount of elements in arr. So I substract 0.15 from `arr[0]` rather than, say, substract 0.1 from `arr[0]` and add 0.05 to `arr[1]`:

```
[-0.2, 0.05, 0.5, 0.8, 1.2]
```

Previous array is also valid, but we have modified 2 elements rather than one.

Also, in case it is possible to generate `good_array` by modifying different elements in `arr`, by default modify the element closer to the edge of the array. But keep in mind the main goal is to generate `good_array` by modifying the minimum number of elemtns in arr.

```
[-0.1, 0.15, 0.5, 0.8, 1.2]
```

Previous array is also valid, but we have modified `arr[1]` rather than the element closer to the edge (`arr[0]`). In case 2 elements have equal distance from edges, modify the one closer to begining of array:

```
[-0.3, 0.15, 0.2, 0.7] # modify arr[1] rather than arr[2]
```

So far I have been doing this manually for small arrays, but I would like a general solution for larger arrays.

Comment: must the order of elements be preserved? Or can you change arr[0] to 1000?

Comment: @juvian Order must be preserved

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I just realized that my original solution was stupid and overcomplicated. Now presenting simple and better solution

## First approach

If I understand your problem correctly, your input array can have some regions, where your condition is not met. For instance:

`array = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]` (first 4 elements)

or:

`array = [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75]` (elements arr[4], arr[5] and arr[6])

To fix that, you have to add (or subtract) some pattern like:

`fixup = [0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` (for the first case)

or:

`fixup = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` (for the second example)

## Second approach

But our current solution has got some problem. Consider a bad area with an "elevation":

`array = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.35, 1.6]` (broken area is within values: 0.6-1.0)

In that case our correct "solution" will be:

`fixup = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25+0.1, 0.0, 0.25+0.1, 0.0, 0.25+0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

which produce:

`good_array = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.95, 0.7, 1.15, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.35, 1.6]`

So to summarize, you have to apply the "patch":

`fixup[i] = threshold+max(difference[i], difference[i-1])`  (for `i` when `i-start_index` is even)

(please note that it will be `-threshold+min(difference[i], difference[i-1])` for negative values)

and:

`fixup[i] = 0` (for `i` when `i-start_index` is odd)

`start_index` is a beginning of the bad region.

## Third approach

Previously mentioned formula doesn't work well for some cases (like `[0.1, 0.3, 0.4]` that it would increment `0.3` up to `0.75` when only `0.65` is sufficient)

Lets try to improve that:

`good_array[i] = max(threshold+array[i-1], threshold+array[i+1])` (for `abs(array[i-1]-array[i+1]) < threshold*2`)

and:

`good_array[i] = (array[i-1]+array[i+1])/2` otherwise.

(you can also choose formula: `good_array[i] = min(-threshold+array[i-1], -threshold+array[i+1])` when it would produce a result closer to original array value, if minimizing difference is also your optimization goal)

## 4th approach

Bad regions of even length are also a threat. I can think about 2 ways to solve it:

- Solution based on a pattern like `[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0]`
- Or based on a pattern like `[0.0, 0.25, -0.25, 0.0]` (We are simply using "the second formula")
- Or `[0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25]` (just including additional element to make bad region length odd -I don't recommend this approach as it would require handling lot of corner cases)

## Corner cases

Please consider also some corner cases (bad region starts or ends at an "edge" of the array):

`good_array[0] = threshold+array[1]`

and:

`good_array[array_size-1] = threshold+array[array_size-2]`

## Final hints

I would suggest to implement lot of unit tests during implementation in order to easily verify correctness of derived formulas and handle some combinations of corner cases. **Bad areas that consist of only one element can be one of them.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is brute force python solution, where we try to fix elements to the right or elements to the left when there is a conflict:

```
def solve(arr, thereshold):
    original = list(arr)

    def solve(idx):
        if idx + 1 >= len(arr):
            return [sum(1 for x in range(len(arr)) if arr[x] != original[x]), list(arr)];

        if arr[idx + 1] - arr[idx] < thereshold:
            copy = list(arr)    

            leftCost = 0
            while idx - leftCost >= 0 and arr[idx + 1] - arr[idx - leftCost] < thereshold * (leftCost + 1):
                arr[idx - leftCost] = arr[idx - leftCost + 1] - thereshold
                leftCost += 1

            left = solve(idx + 1)
            for cost in range(leftCost):
                arr[idx - cost] = copy[idx - cost]  

            rightCost = 0
            while idx + rightCost + 1 < len(arr) and arr[idx + rightCost + 1] - arr[idx] < thereshold * (rightCost + 1):
                arr[idx + rightCost + 1] = arr[idx + rightCost ] + thereshold
                rightCost += 1

            right = solve(idx + 1)
            for cost in range(rightCost):
                arr[idx + cost + 1] = copy[idx + cost + 1]  

            if right[0] < left[0]:
                return right
            elif left[0] < right[0]:
                return left
            else:
                return left if idx - left[0] <= len(arr) - idx - right[0] else right 

        else:
            return solve(idx + 1)               


    return solve(0)

print(solve([0,0.26,0.63,0.7,1.2], 0.25))
```

Comment: This works, but only sometimes. The main goal is to modify the minimum number of elements in `arr`. So for example, in `[0,0.26,0.63,0.7,1.2]`, `arr[3]` should be modified and the  proper solution would be `[0,0.26,0.63,0.88,1.2]`, we only have modified one element. Your function modifies 3 elements and returns `[-0.05, 0.2, 0.45, 0.7, 1.2]`

Comment: @Brenlla with thereshold 0.25, I get [1, [0, 0.26, 0.63, 0.88, 1.2]] as result, maybe you modified something?

Comment: I modified `solve` so it would accept `arr` as input argument. That must have changed something. Also, I assume `idx` is an index. Do I have to call `solve` with `idx` 0? Could you please add one example for running `solve`?

Comment: @Brenlla yes idx is index and in my code you can see I am calling solve(0). Can add arr as parameter when I get home. An easy way though is encapsulate whole code in a function that takes arr and threshold and returns the solve function evaluated at index 0